# How do I return the lowest value in one field, eliminating duplicates based on another?

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, very new to Access 2016 / SQL. I'm trying to make the following set of data:

[image: Raw Data]

Which needs to be:

[image: Desired Result]

The logic here is I need to find the lowest TCO for each product, within each retailer, that must have a size greater than 999. Can someone help explain this to me please.

Thanks,

UPDATED: Based on comments I've updated requirements and simplified data :)

Raw Data: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3X3y.png)

Expected Data: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoXPQ.png)

Comment: If anyone updates their answer with an exact solution for the update criteria, that is their prerogative. However, one tradition has always been that a great question 1) outlines all of the criteria from the start and 2) includes an attempted solution showing effort of your own research and understanding.  Now that the answers have given you a great example of working solutions, you should really try to understand the details and craft the final solution yourself.

Comment: For what it's worth, I suggest taking apomene's solution and updating the criteria (i.e. WHERE clause) and adding additional aggregate columns according to what you expect the results to look like.  See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sql-aggregate-functions-a810ee71-c1cd-43d7-9c55-8005f1893be5

Comment: Thanks C Perkins. Yeah - I tried to ask the question with detail but you quickly realise what makes sense to you does not to others, even if you think you included all the facts, you haven't! thanks all

Answer (score 1):

USE `group by` and `min` like:

```
    SELECT Product,Retailer,MIN(CTO) from myTable 
     where size>999 GROUP BY Product,Retailer
```

Comment: This looks like it worked! Thank you. Two more things, if I had another variable similar to SIZE, do I just use the & command and put it in? E.g. "where size>999 & weight>500"? I did try this but the result returned was incorrect. I also need my final table to show the SIZE result, so in the example above, for it to show that it is 1000.

Comment: `AND` is the proper logical operator in SQL.  The operator `&` performs a string concatenation in VBA in Access.

Comment: How can I add the extra info I need without it affecting the calculation? I want to see Size (and the new field Weight) in my table output.

Comment: What is Weight? Now you have more columns?

Comment: Sorry yeah, it is basically the same in the code: WHERE (((Table2.size)>19999) AND ((Table2.weight)<80)) is used to filter (which I think it is correctly). But I would like my end result to show "Ok, here is that TCO for that Product, and the corresponding size and weight is..." Thanks

Comment: @BenThompson Edit your question, post sample data and expected results with the new requirement and explain what you want in the results in case there are more than 1 sizes and weights for a minimum tco.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the columns in the result then you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select
  t.*
from tablename t
where 
  t.size > 999
  and
  not exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where product = t.product and retailer = t.retailer and size > 999 and tco < t.tco
  )
```

Comment: The key difference here is not necessarily that it returns "all the columns", since the other answer can be updated with something like `MIN(size)` to also return all columns. Rather this query will potentially return multiple rows with overlapping values in the criteria columns.  In other words, it will return **all rows** that match the conditions, whereas the other answer with aggregate results will return **only one row** for each set of unique criteria values.  If there are never "overlapping" rows, then the results are identical.  Otherwise, these will return different number of rows.

Comment: *this query will potentially return multiple rows* correct and I believe it should (if there are multiple rows) because there is no condition to restrict the result to just 1 row for each case since there is also the column `size` which may vary or not. If the expected result did not contain the column size then only `group by product, retailer` would be enough.

Comment: My comment was primarily for the OP since they indicated that they are "very new".  I find that often indicates that they don't understand fully the concept of aggregates, filtered data sets, etc.  If they test both answers with data that is too simple, or just naively assume that both answers are equivalent, then they might be frustrated later when results are not what they expect.  A lack of condition in the question, especially for newbies, is not an indication of what "should be".  It's not a matter of what you "believe it should" be, rather the OP needs to decide that.

Comment: I agree. The OP will try the solutions proposed here and I hope that the difference in the results will make it clear to them that the requirement was not fully clarified.

Comment: I am reading your comments and trying to understand them :) is apomene solution going to cause issues down the line for some reason? On the face of it, it seems to have solved my issue (bar the extra comments I've just added).

Comment: @BenThompson Both solutions are correct, but to choose 1 of them you must try them. My code returns all the columns of the table (including size) and if there is a case that 2 rows satisfy the conditions then both are returned because both have the minimum tco.

Comment: This is precisely why I added my comments, but sorry they cause difficulty understanding.  To realize what I am trying to say, you need to have rows in the source data that match the same criteria and then ask yourself "Do I want all the rows that match the condition, or do I only want one row for all unique matches to the condition."  What if you have `Laptop, a1.com, 450, 1000` and also `Laptop, a1.com, 450, 1500`?  Both of those match the same conditions, but do you necessarily want/need both rows or only one output row which represents both source rows?

Comment: @BenThompson your sample data do not contain rows like the example that CPrekins provided. But if it did contain what would you expect as a result?

Comment: In that situation, I would only want the lowest TCO above 999, so just one result show present itself "Laptop, a1.com, 450, 1000".

Comment: You mean lowest per size?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you are saying. No - in that case, if the TCOs were the same, I would want the highest size returned.

Comment: @BenThompson It happens in the new sample data you posted that the row containing the greater size has also the greater weight and this row you pick for the results. Is this the only case that could exist? Because if there are 2 rows with the same  tco and the one contains the greater size and the lowest weight from the 2 rows then what do you expect as result?

Comment: My bad. Filter first by weight then sort ascending on TCO. Display lowest TCO and the corresponding size and weight

Answer (score 0):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.size > 999 and
      t.tco = (select min(t2.tco)
               from t as t2
               where t2.product = t.product and
                     t2.retailer = t.retailer and
                     t2.size > 999
              );
```

Comment: @CPerkins . . . Yes.  The question is asking for the minimum.  Thank you.